# Showing that $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ is unbiased for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$

Tags: regression, self-study, maximum-likelihood

I denote $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ as the MLE for the vector of unknown parameters.

I've been given the following hint for the question:
'For a random vector $\boldsymbol{V}$and deterministic matrices A and B (of agreeing dimensions) that $E(A\boldsymbol{V}) = A\boldsymbol{V}$ and $E(\boldsymbol{V}^{T}B) = \boldsymbol{V}^{T}B$.'

I don't know how I'm meant to show $E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) = \boldsymbol{\beta}$ **using the hint**. I've done the question without the hint.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Think about the expression for beta hat...is there a random vector in there?

Comment: A bigger hint is can you write beta hat as a function of beta...which you must have if you claim to have proven the result

Comment: @user 2879934 Yes, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$ where $Y$ is the random vector. But I'm not sure if the next step is just $E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$?

Comment: That's not a valid operation, you have to take expected value of both sides

Comment: Yes, this is where I get stuck. I thought you do $E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) = E((X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y) = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$ since $(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$ is a deterministic matrix an $Y$ is a random vector? But of course, I know this is wrong. :l I tried to use the hint.

Comment: You're on the right track. Hint: substitute $\mathbf{y} = X \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Ah, I'm just really confused about the hint I've been given. If the hint were $E(AV) = AE(V)$ then I'd be able to substitute appropriately and solve the problem :l

Comment: Pretend you were given that form of the hint, because it makes sense and is correct, whereas the form quoted in your question is useless and generally wrong.

Comment: @whuber Well, that makes perfect sense - I thought I was going crazy! Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), if you think you've got it now :)